# How do you remove newline character in the middle of file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, scripting

File structure:

```
Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4
123|456|abcdefg
Tel.: 689346589934, xyz
lckhasfkl|abc
```

I want to remove the newline character from 'col3' only.Please suggest

Comment: which newline character are you talking about? You question isn't clear.

Comment: I have newline character n col3, as you can see the data is splitted into multiple lines in col3. I want the data to be in single line for col3

Comment: Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4

123|456|abcdefgTel.: 689346589934,xyzlckhasfkl|abc     I need output in this format

Comment: @Azhar please edit _your question_

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I wish you hadn't deleted your answer.  I found it quite useful.  In particular I had never used the `getline` function in `awk` and your example is very clear.

Comment: @Wildcard - how can you see that? i needed 10k rep before i could, i think.

Comment: @mikeserv, I opened the tab a couple hours ago, and when I got around to actually looking at the tab and then clicking "upvote", it said "You can't upvote this answer because it's been deleted" or similar wording.  :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed -e :1 -e '/|.*|.*|/!{N;b1' -e '}' -e 's/\n/ /g' < your-file
Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4
123|456|abcdefg Tel.: 689346589934, xyz lckhasfkl|abc
```

Or the `awk` equivalent:

```
awk -F '|' '{while (NF<4) {getline more; $0 = $0 " " more};print}' < your-file
```

Both *get* the next line and append to the line with a space as long as the line doesn't contain at least 3 `|` characters (4 fields).

If other fields (except for the 4th one as otherwise we couldn't know where a new record starts) may contain newlines and you only want to replace newlines in the 3rd one:

```
sed '
 :1
 /|.*|.*|/!{
   N;b1
 }
 :2
 s/\n\([^|]*|[^|]*$\)/ \1/
 t2' < your-file
```

Or:

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '
  {
    while (NF < 4) {getline more; $0 = $0 "\n" more}
    gsub("\n", " ", $3)
    print
  }' < your-file
```

Comment: @Azhar, please edit your question with the input and expected output.

Comment: Input file
                                                                                                                      
Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6|Col7
71655667|68630423|some text
Tel.: 1234567 Mail:
abcdef@xya.com
STYTYPE_PLAIN_TEXT|OIGINAL|GEMAN|abc|xyz


Expected Output
                                                                                                             
Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6|Col7
71655667|68630423|some textTel.: 1234567 Mail:abcdef@xya.comSTYTYPE_PLAIN_TEXT|OIGINAL|GEMAN|abc|xyz

Comment: I have added the input file format and expected output, can you please provide the answer asap.its urgent

Comment: Which sed requires all those `-e`'s ?

Comment: @User112638726, most. All the traditional ones descending from the original implementation like in most commercial Unices. Most BSDs as well. The POSIX spec for sed mandates them. GNU `sed` (and `ssed` which is more or less the same) are probably the only ones where they can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed`:

```
sed -e:d -e's/|/|/3;t' -e'N;s/\n//;td' < in >out
```

The `sed` works a loop by substituting the third pipe character on a line for itself. When the substitution `t`ests successful `sed` branches away - and so autoprints pattern space - and starts the script from the top with the next input line, if any. But when it fails `sed` appends the `N`ext line to pattern space, `s///`ubstitutes away the intervening newline delimiter, and then the second `t`est passes and `sed` branches back to the `:d`elim label to look for a third pipe again.

Comment: The above command removes all the newline characters and put everything in one line. But i want remove newlines only from col3 and keep the new lines at the end of the file

Comment: Input

Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6|Col7
71655667|68630423|text
Tel.: 1234567 Mail:
abcdef@xya.com
-----------------------------------------------------------------
STYTYPE_PLAIN_TEXT|OIGINAL|GEMAN|abc|xyz
62655667|68567423|abcdef
Tel.: 1234567 Mail:
abcdef@xya.com
STYTYPE_PLAIN_TEXT|OIGINAL|GEMAN|abc|xyz

Output

Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6|Col7
71655667|68630423|textTel.: 1234567 Mail:abcdef@xya.comSTYTYPE_PLAIN_TEXT|OIGINAL|GEMAN|abc|xyz
62655667|68567423|abcdefTel.: 1234567 Mail:abcdef@xya.comSTYTYPE_PLAIN_TEXT|OIGINAL|GEMAN|abc|xyz

Comment: @Azhar - what is that? that's the way you want it formatted? it's hard to believe because the comments don't usually do formatting very well. Also, I don't relation to column 3. But the above command should branch away and print the line when there are at least 3 `|` pipe characters on a line.

Comment: Thanks you so much, This works perfect Can you please explian code in more details

Comment: I have one more requirement with respect to above command..I want to replace the | (pipe) also in the col3 along with newline character.How can I achieve this

Comment: @Azhar - well, i require that you put your example data in your question.

Comment: @Azhar ... Well, it's already doing a substitution on the third pipe anyway - it's how it checks. so just change `s/|/|/3` to `s/|/something else/3`

Comment: Input

col1|col2|col3
abc|zm|r
p|qr|
xyz|123


Output

Col1|Col2|Col3
abc|zmrpqrxyz|123

Comment: I have given the example data..If you see the data between pipe(|) after 'c' to the pipe before '1' in input file has contain many pipes(|). I want to remove those pipes also..hope I clear my requirement

Comment: @Azhar - i have no idea what that means. please *edit your question*. don't put the data in the comments. it's automatically stripped of all formatting here. No. it is **not clear**.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253851/remove-newline-and-in-col3          Please refer the link I have posted new question with clear example and let me know if I am still not clear

Comment: Hey Mike, It would be great if you can give the answer as I need it bit urgent

Comment: @Azhar - answer to what?!? i don't understand the question. it looks like you're asking how to delimit your columns on delimiters you also say are not valid for some reason. so what makes a column?

Comment: I have edited the input file and the double quotes defines the columns...http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253851/remove-newline-and-in-col2